# Flex Focus out handler runtime error 1009 , How to fix?

Tags: apache-flex, focus, runtime, movieclip

I am getting these weird runtime errors. I am using Flex 3.5 SDK with flash player set to 10.0.00.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

at mx.flash::UIMovieClip/removeFocusEventListeners()[E:\dev\flex\sdk\frameworks\projects\flash-integration\src\mx\flash\UIMovieClip.as:2368]
 at mx.flash::UIMovieClip/focusOutHandler()[E:\dev\flex\sdk\frameworks\projects\flash-integration\src\mx\flash\UIMovieClip.as:2411]

I get this errors when I click on any other control in a popup. I am using buttons, textarea,textinput,and a list.  I dont know how to fix this ... It would be great if someone pull me out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it's gonna be hard to pinpoint. This error could occur if you are trying to 1) access the property of an object that hasn't been created by the time the focus out handler is called, or 2) access the property of an object that ins't referenced in the focus out handler.

Make sure any non-local variables in the focus out handler reference an object that has been created somewhere in your application **before the call to the focus out handler**. Also, make sure a reference to each object gets passed into the focus out handler by declaring those variables globally, or passing the object to the function as a parameter.

Post the code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to remove focus from your UIMovieClips before removing them from the stage:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/658335?tstart=-1

Or just target flash player 10 where this bug is fixed.

Add this code to the top of any function that may remove a UImovieClip from the display list:

```
if (stage)
{
    stage.focus = null;
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris..

Actually I am not using any sort of Focus handlers or not even setting any focus to any object. And one more thing is these errors are showing just in my machine, and not in others.

I have installed debug flash player too and others did not. May be the problem is because of that flash debugger version. Even when I started working in a new machine, even there the same problem comes.


These errors are just irritating ...

Comment: Try using your flash movie clips as skins for a button insted of using them directly.